# (Android Repository Pattern) Update phone database data with deleted items from web

Tags: android, repository-pattern, android-room, android-architecture-components

I'm implementing the repository pattern to my project in Android but my main problem is how to control the data the users remove from the web.

Let's take the [Github Browser Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components) example.

[image: Github Browser proccess]

Possibles solutions:

- Remove all the Repos and insert the new list everytime I fetch for that user.
- Remove all the Repos and insert the new list everytime I fetch for that user if the last fetch was 3 min or more ago
- Remove all the Repos table when the app start (so it will show the 
  real data when the app close and open again).
- Implement something like force update (Swipe and refresh) and remove all the Repos and insert them again.

What do you think about how to solve this problem?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

"Remove all the Repos and insert the new list everytime I fetch for that user."

This is a good approach as you still can have something to show to the user while waiting for the api call to complete.
I'm currently doing this in an app I'm working on at the moment using Room database and observing it using LiveData which makes managing the dataset almost trivial.